# When I resize a label from code rubbish displays briefly on the new empty space

Tags: .net, c++, winforms, visual-studio-2010, custom-controls

I'm resizing and moving controls.

The code is working as I want, except that I'm getting a black rectangle displayed briefly in the new space before the correct display appears.

The moving of a control is done when another control changes its height.

I make the changes from OnPaint in a class derived from Label and it doesn't seem to matter if I call the base OnPaint first or last.

```
public ref class ResizeLabel : public System::Windows::Forms::Label
{
    private void resizelabel()
    {
        int width = ... ;
        int height = ... ;
        __super::Width = width;
        __super::Height = height;
        this->LinkedControl->Top = __super::Top + __super::Height;
    }

    protected: virtual void OnPaint(System::Windows::Forms::PaintEventArgs^  e) override {
       resizeLabel();
       __super::OnPaint(e);
    }
};
```

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm probably doing something wrong, but I don't know what.

One logically wrong thing that you're doing is resizing from within a paint event.  That makes no logical sense.  Inside a paint event, the portion of the control to be repainted has already been determined (and is indeed supplied in the event arguments).  Resizing doesn't change that.  It simply marks other parts of the control as invalid (if the size increases), and thus due for more paint events in the future.

Resize inside the event or method that actually causes the resize to happen, whatever that may be, not inside the event that causes the control to be painted.  If resizing needs to happen whenever the text of the label changes, for example, put the resizing code inside the method that is triggered by the text changing.  "My text has changed, I need to work out a new size for myself, the new unpainted parts of me that that creates to be repainted at leisure in the usual fashion." is the logic for such a control.  The same goes for other causes for resizing.

Comment: You are right, if I make my changes elsewhere the black rectangle effect is no longer there.  Unfortunately, just using the Paint event did have the effect I was after and I've yet to find the logic which works as I want.  I can't believe how many events are caused even without my additions.  It all seems horrendously complex, but it does seem to be the case that changing the size in the paint event is what causes the problem.  Thanks.